# MySQL: INSERT INTO table (SELECT * FROM other_table) with custom values appended?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I combine values from a table with my own values and insert them in another table? Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (
    SELECT * FROM `other_table`,
    `custom_column` = 'custom value',
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT 'Value for column1', column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

*'Value for column1'* is a fix value and *column2* and *column3* in select are from the table1

Comment: Is it valid to use a statement such as this one? `SELECT *, 'value' FROM other_table?`

Comment: @user8555937 yes. But if you use `select *` you can not control the order. So the order of the insert table column must be the same as in the select table

Comment: `SELECT *, 'value' FROM other_table` - It is valid if number of columns in table "other_table" + 1 is equal to the number of columns in the table you are inserting data into. Here you can see that this is not possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b502cfa9d1d3e31ca8e2c626765c170e